# How to prove the Heine-Borel property in $\mathbb{R}$ for closed and bounded sets in general?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have managed to prove that for all closed intervals $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, $[a,b]$  has the Heine-Borel property, i.e., every open cover of $[a,b]$ has a finite subcover. How do I extend this to closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in general? Does it follow from the particular case of closed intervals?

Comment: Hint: Every closed and bounded set is contained in one such interval

Comment: So it seems you would have to prove that any closed set contained in a closed interval also has the Heine-Borel property.  How would you go about that?

Comment: You use non-standard and confusing terminology; see my answer. $[a,b]$ is compact and $(\Bbb R,|.|)$ has the Heine-Borel property.

Comment: If $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of the closed subspace, add $\Bbb R\setminus A$ to it to get a new cover of the space for which we know that every open cover has a finite subcover. Use that finite subcover (remove the extra set). Done.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry @HennoBrandsma for the confusing notation. Thanks for clarifying the definition of 'compact' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a closed subset of a compact space (compact is defined by "every open cover has a finite subcover") then $A$ also is compact.

Suppose $A$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$.

By boundedness we find some closed interval $[m,M]$ so that $A \subseteq [m,M]$.

$A$ is closed in $[m,M]$ so it is compact too.

Note that compactness is the correct name for the cover notion and Heine-Borel property is the name for the property that a closed and bounded subset of a metric space is compact.

All bounded closed intervals are compact in $\Bbb R$ and that is the key to the fact that $\Bbb R$ has the Heine-Borel property in its standard metric.

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344312/clarify-if-a%e2%8a%86-mathcal-r-1-big-mathcal-ra-big-and-if-mathcal-r-big-ma), please? Forgive the bother.