# Clarify if $A⊆\mathcal R^{-1}\big[\mathcal R[A]\big]$ and if $\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]=B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal R$ for any relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, relations

**Definition**

A set $\mathcal R$ is a binary relation if any its element is an ordered pair. In particular a function $\mathcal f$ is a binary relation such that
$$
(x,y_1),(x,y_2)\in\mathcal f\Leftrightarrow y_1=y_2
$$
for any $x$.

**Definition**

Given a relation $\mathcal R$ the subset $\text{dom }\mathcal R$ of $\bigcup\big(\bigcup\mathcal R\big)$ whose elements are the first coordinates of $\mathcal R$ is called the domain of $\mathcal R$.

**Definition**

Given a relation $\mathcal R$ the subset $\text{ran}\;\mathcal R$ of $\bigcup\big(\bigcup\mathcal R\big)$ whose elements are the second coordinates of $\mathcal R$ is called the range of $\mathcal R$.

So with this definitions is not hard to show that
$$
\mathcal R\subseteq\text{dom }\mathcal R\times\text{ran }\mathcal R
$$
so that we can give the following definition.

**Definition**

If $\mathcal R$ is a relation then the image $\mathcal R[A]$ of $A$ and the preimage $\mathcal R^{-1}[B]$ of $B$ under $\mathcal R$ are the sets
$$
\mathcal R[A]:=\{y\in\text{ran }\mathcal R:x\mathcal Ry\,\text{for some }x\in A\}\\
\mathcal R^{-1}[B]:=\{x\in\text{dom }\mathcal R:x\mathcal Ry\,\text{for some }y\in B\}
$$

---

---

Now if $\mathcal f$ is a function then it is a well-known result that
$$
A\subseteq\mathcal f^{-1}\big[\mathcal f[A]\big]\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\mathcal f\big[\mathcal f^{-1}[B]\big]=B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal f
$$
for any $A\subseteq\text{dom }\mathcal f$ and for any other set $B$ so that I ask myself if this these results hold replacing $\mathcal f$ with a general binary relation $\mathcal R$.

---

1. So first of all I observed that if $A\subseteq\text{dom }\mathcal R$ then there exist $b\in\bigcup\big(\bigcup\mathcal R\big)$  such that $a\mathcal R b$ and necessarly $b\in\mathcal R[A]$ because $b$ is surely an element of $\text{ran }\mathcal R$. So I concluded that the inclusion
   $$
   A\subseteq\mathcal R^{-1}\big[\mathcal R[A]\big]
   $$
   holds for any $A\subseteq\text{dom }\mathcal R$, **provided that the argumentations I gave are correct**.
2. Now if $y$ is an element of $B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal f$ then there exists $x\in\text{dom }\mathcal R$ such that $x\mathcal R y$ and surely this such $x$ is an element of $\mathcal R^{-1}[B]$ by definition; on the other hand for **this such** $x$ there exist an element (**precisely** $y$) of $\text{ran }f$ related with $x$ through $\mathcal R$ so that $y$ is an element of $\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]$ but we initially assume that $y$ is an element of $B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal R$ so that we can conclude that the inclusion
   $$
   B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal R\subseteq\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]
   $$
   holds.

Now unfortunately I was not able to prove that the inverse inclusion holds: indeed conversely if $y$ is an element of $\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]$ then there exist $x\in\mathcal R^{-1}[B]$ such that $x\mathcal R y$ and this last element $x$ is such that $x\mathcal Ry'$ for any $y'\in B$ so that if the relation $\mathcal R$ was a function then surely $y'=y$ and so we could conclude that
$$
\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]\subseteq B\cap\text{ran }R
$$
since obviously $y'$ is an element of $\text{ran }R$. So by the last argumentation I suspect that the identity
$$
\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]=B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal R
$$
does not hold when the relation $\mathcal R$ is not a function but unfortunately I was not able to elaborate a counterexample so that I thought to pay a specific question where I ask to clarify this and where I ask also if the argumentations I gave to prove that
$$
A\subseteq\mathcal R^{-1}\big[\mathcal R[A]\big]
$$
are correct.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Oh, forgive: I missed the other term. So I ask if the sets $\mathcal R\big[\mathcal R^{-1}[B]\big]$ and $B\cap\text{ran }\mathcal R$ are equal where $\mathcal R$ is an arbitrary binary relation. Anyway now I edit the question.

Comment: Question edited, I hope now there no more typos.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the edit about grammar!!! Sorry if my english is no so good. Anyway while you are reflecting can you say if the argumentation I gave to prove that $A\subseteq\mathcal R^{-1}\big[\mathcal R[A]\big]$ are correct or rather if also this inclusion could be false for a general arbitrary relation?

Comment: It's true, see my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning for

$$A \subseteq R^{-1}\left[R[A]\right] \text{ if } A \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(R)$$

is quite correct: recap let $x \in A$.
That $A \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(R)$ gives us some $y$ so that $(x,y) \in R$. By definition $y \in R[A]$ and again by definition $x \in R^{-1}\left[R[A]\right]$. QED.

(notational side-remark : I always use $R$ for a relation, capitals like $A,B$ for subsets, and $x,y$ for elements; It's easier on the typing and my eyes. When I see $\mathcal R$ in this context I go up a type and think that it's a set of relations, not just one. That's my mathematical upbringing, I suppose; even in high school they do it like that)

Also, $$B \cap \operatorname{ran}(R) \subseteq R\left[R^{-1}[B]\right]$$ also holds quite easily:

Let $y \in B \cap \operatorname{ran}(R)$. So $y \in B$ and for some $x$ we have $(x,y) \in R$. So by definition $x \in R^{-1}[B]$ (as witnessed by $y \in B$) and again by definition $y \in R\left[R^{-1}[B]\right]$, as now witnessed by $x$. QED.

The reverse does *not* hold as you suspected. Trivial almost minimal example:

Let $R=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ then $\operatorname{ran}(R)=\{1,2\}$ and taking $B=\{2\}$ we see that $R^{-1}[B]=\{1,2\}$ and $R[R^{-1}[B]]=\{1,2\}$ and we have inequality of the latter set and $B \cap \operatorname{ran}(R)= \{2\}$...

Comment: Okay, very well: I wait for the counterexample. In any case, thank you for having responded to my request for help: you was really kind, so thanks really.

Comment: @HennoBransma You are right: I must learn to have more faith in me and so not pay question about trivial thing thinking that a specter in my mind impedes to me to see who knows what: e.g. the inclusion $A\subseteq R^{-1}\big[R[A]\big]$ is trivial and moreover with more commitement I could also had find the counterexample by mysefl. So forgive me.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro no excuse yourself. It’s a very common type of question to ask for proof confirmation. Getting feedback can be a fast way to learn. The example comes as soon as you create a truly multivalued relation and try simple sets. That’s how I did it too.

Comment: Okay, I will get it in mind: "truly multivalued relation and try **simple** sets". In any case if it is common therefore I will continue to pay verification questions: indeed when I stared to study **seriously** Mathematics the first difficult I had was the lack of a  student fellow with which I could discuss and exactly this lack was the reason for which I signed up on this site and honestly I must admit that it was really much precious since he gave me the opportunity to discuss not only with other students but even with much expert people as you and exactly this let me to grow very much.

Comment: So I thanks you very much for all you learn to me.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I'm happy to be of service, thx. It's quite fun to keep using my old knowledge on topology...